# OpenLayers Plugin not working in QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, openlayers-2, qgis-2.8

I am using QGIS 2.8.1. I have installed the OpenLayers Plug, however it is not showing up in my list of plugins. I confirmed it's installed in the plugin manager.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are running Qgis 2.8.1.

The openlayers plugin has nothing to do with the JavaScript library Openlayers 2 or 3 !

Anyway to access this plugin in Qgis, you should go the tab 'Internet' and it shoud be there !

[image]

Comment: The plugin surely has something to do with the Javascript library openlayers.js. You will find it in the `./qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/weblayers/html` folder.