# QGIS 2.81. crashes when using OpenLayers

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.8

I just installed QGIS 2.8 Wien to get access to OpenLayers (I could not install it under 2.4, and had to uninstall completely and reinstall 2.8).
It was working apparently, but when I tried to get to the OpenLayers

[OpenLayers Plugin not working in QGIS 2.8.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142985/open-layers-plugin-not-working-in-qgis-2-8-1)

The last comment in that question is that the plugin has something to do with a ./qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/weblayers/htfolder, was of no help.

That question links to this one:

[Where is the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121085/where-is-the-openlayers-plugin-in-qgis-2-6)

I checked out if the OpenLayers plugin was installed and activated in the "Installed Plugins" list. It is, but it doesn't show the OpenLayers  under the menu "Web" yet. I try to use "OpenLayers" under the "Plugins" menu, selecting "Add Google Satellite Layer" but QGIS crashes completely (closes).

I could not comment or answer in the mentioned questions, so I started a new question because the problem is still not solved.

Comment: I would probably suggest to try installing [OpenLayers](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) manually by downloading the latest version. Delete the plugin folder from  `./qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin` and unzip the downloaded file to the same location. I experienced this problem twice and this method worked for me so here's hoping it will for you too :)

Comment: Hello! I tried to install the latest version (2.10 Pisa) but I got dependencies problems, that's why I tried with 2.8 that is LTR and should work, doesn't it?
Anyway, I am a newby in this issues of open software, deleting plugins and so, how do I do it?
Thanks

Comment: I use QGIS 2.8.2 on Windows and it works for me. To manually delete the plugin, go to the directory `C:\Users\you\.qgis2\python\plugins\` and delete the folder `openlayers_plugin`. Then from the link in my previous comment, download and unzip the compressed file. You will get a folder which you can then move to `C:\Users\you\.qgis2\python\plugins\`. Make sure to restart QGIS if it is already running. This is how to manually install plugins but as I said, it may or may not solve your problem.